# How to start \beginequation at (1) for each proof?

Tags: math-mode, equations

Here is a visual representation of what I am talking about:
[image: "Proof"]

How do I make it so that at each proof, the counter resets to (1)?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The equation number should probably be relative to the theorem, rather that just a cold restart every time. Otherwise you'll be left with duplicate equation numbers. Would you agree?

Comment: Do you have equation numbers outside proofs? If so, how should they be?

Comment: I guess the problem is that even though I wrote \begin{theorem} statement, I couldn't get LaTex to recognize it. Is it possible that I am missing a package that allows it to recognize and show theorems?
I have \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
I am a newbie, so I am sorry if I'm making a rookie mistake.

Comment: @natsushima, define `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` in preamble.

Comment: Thank you so much; that worked perfectly! However, it only shows the theorems, but it doesn't reset the counter for equations within theorems...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do would be to create your own proof environment that resets the equation number:

```
\newenvironment{myproof}{\setcounter{equation}{0}\begin{proof}}{\end{proof}}
```

Or, if preferred, save the current equation number going into the proof so it can be restored afterwards:

```
\newcounter{savenumber}
\newenvironment{myproof}{%
\setcounter{savenumber}{\value{equation}}\setcounter{equation}{0}%
\begin{proof}}%
{\end{proof}%
\setcounter{equation}{\value{savenumber}}%
}
```

Example use and output

```
%\usepackage{amsmath} % preamble
%\usepackage{amsthm} % preamble
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    x=1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    x=2
\end{equation}
\begin{myproof}
    \begin{equation}
        x=3
    \end{equation}
\end{myproof}
\begin{equation}
    x=4
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

Both are likely confusing to a reader and the `hyperref` package will complain (and not be able to correct link each equation), if you are using that. A better approach would be to add a visual identifier (and one for `hyperref`, if applicable) for equations in your new proof environment, such as:

```
\newcounter{savenumber}
\newenvironment{myproof}{%
\renewcommand{\theequation}{p.\arabic{equation}}% Visual identifier
% \renewcommand{\theHequation}{p.\arabic{equation}}% Uncomment if using hyperref
\setcounter{savenumber}{\value{equation}}\setcounter{equation}{0}%
\begin{proof}}%
{\end{proof}%
\setcounter{equation}{\value{savenumber}}
}
```

Then

[image: output2]